# Nikon D3400 black line in pictures

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, photography

I got an used nikon d3400, I took some pictures but the all have a black line at the bottom (covers about 20% of the image). How could this be fix?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening when you shoot with flash(external) or always?
If with flash, then shoot with the shutter at 1/200 s or slower as the highest flash sync speed is 1/200s on Nikon d3400.
I hope I could be of help.